# Contracts, Recruiters, and fraud?

Tags: recruitment

So this is a long story but I will try to make it short

I reached out to a recruiter as I was looking to get a new job. The recruiter had set up various interviews with one being at a great company with an awesome culture! The recruiter reached out after the interview and offered me a contract to hire position. I took it.

A month went by and I decided to ask the recruiter on my contract to hire agreement and they assured me with a specific date of my transition to full time.

I questioned this however as the recruiter wasn't confident and asked my Manger  (who hired and interviewed me ) and he was confused. He said that they had signed me up for a 3 month contract with no full time in the near future.

So what do I do? What can I do? I have it in writing where I was told multiple times that I would be hired full time at X date. But the company I work for had no idea about this!

I want to keep working for this company but I would rather do it with another consulting firm. What makes it worse is that the company I work for has a none disclosure agreement which means I'm stuck with the recruiters who tricked me.

Do you guys know what my options could be? Is my contact even valid at this point?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't give you legal advice here, which is what you should seek. At the very least I would break ties with that company right away.

Comment: This is typically called "bait and switch". You will find attorneys that specialize in workplace issues will find this an attractive use of their time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what your recruiter says differs from the actual company. Then something is wrong with the recruiter. You may not be able to continue under another consulting firm, but that's no reason not to try and continue under yourself.

In any event I would not use the recruiter any more.

Comment: How could I continue under myself? I didn't know this was an option!

Comment: @calcazar.  form your own company, and accept a corp to corp contract.  Look those up, I believe they are off topic here.

Comment: I did just this and I couldn't be any happier :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the US, in most states, the contract you sign with your employer or contracting company will always be `employment-at-will`, which means either you or the employer can terminate the contract for any reason, with or without cause (some exceptions like ADA, racism, gender/religious/sexual bias etc exists of course) So, at the end of the 3 months, they can come back and say, we do not need your services anymore and let you go. Unfortunately, the agreement you signed, has very little to no value, unless there are stipulations against early termination of contract etc, which I highly doubt, unless you are a C-Level employee.

Let me tell you what is going to happen at the end of the 3 months, as I have been in the same situation more than once. They will come and tell you there is a management change and they are waiting for the go-ahead for permanent employment. Or if you confront them right now, they wil do the pee-pee dance around the subject and even tell you that your manager is not aware of it or can not talk about it but they have insider knowledgeand it will happen. Just give them a little more time and they will drag you until the place you are working, will no longer need you. If the pay is good and the position seems solid with an open end, it mighht not be bad, but if you took the position for a pittance of compensations and the only thing that you were interested in was the permanent hiring part, strat looking for a new position right now, at least on the down-low. Whatever the contracting agency says, the hiring manager knows what the company needs are. If he is telling you they brought you in for 3 months, and if you, even slightly, made your displeasure known, they might not want you for the long term as it is not a good vibe for the workplace.

You have a decision to make.